# value in directive not changing even after its input changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

my main controller code is as follows

```
var self = this;
self.info = {};

Restangular.all('detail').post(this.postbody).then(function(data){
        // this.items = data.tiles;
        self.items = Restangular.copy(data);        
        self.info = self.items.pd;        
        console.log(self.info);

    });
```

the template for my main controller is as follows

```
<div ng-controller="prddetail as prd">
  <pdinfotile dat=prd.info></pdinfotile>
<div>
```

In my directive I have used @ for one way binding and displayed the value but when new values gets updated it is not getting displayed after call from restangular and these values are not updated in directives attribute. How do I proceed thanks in advance.

Note:

```
angular.module('brandmarshal')
  .directive('pdinfotile',function () {
     return{
         scope:{
          dat:'@'
         },
         restrict : 'E',
         templateUrl:'../../templates/pd/pd_info.html',
         controllerAs:'ctrl',
         bindToController:true,
         controller: function() {
             var self = this;
             self.obj = JSON.parse(self.dat);
             console.log(self.obj);
         }
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong binding value setup.

@ is for passing in a string, etc.

= is for two way binding - kind of hacky considered now with enforcing 1 way flow.

< is the single way binding you are looking for!

for example:

`angular.module('brandmarshal')
  .directive('pdinfotile',function () {
     return{
         scope:{
          dat:'<' //<------single way binding or try a = for 2 way binding
         },
         restrict : 'E',
         templateUrl:'../../templates/pd/pd_info.html',
         controllerAs:'ctrl',
         bindToController:true,
         controller: function() {
             var self = this;
             self.obj = JSON.parse(self.dat);
             console.log(self.obj);
         }
     }
  });`

Comment: could you provide an example how to use < or = for solving this problem

Comment: should I pass <customdir a=data.obj></customdir> instead of  <customdir a={{data.obj}}></customdir>

Comment: <customdir a=data.obj></customdir> - by setting the binding up as an 'object' syntax angular knows what the type is